# How do you type a character with its ASCII code?

Tags: macos, internationalization

I need to type the form feed character 0x0C in ASCII on my Mac. Is there any way to do this? I've tried using "Emoji and Symbols" from the Edit menu, but it's not in there.

Answer (score 18):

Add Unicode Hex Input as your Keyboard.  Hold the option key while typing.

[image: Unicode]

Comment: Thanks for answering. I think this would work too, but the character map is more convenient.

Answer (score 16):

It's there for me in Character Viewer (Emoji & Symbols, expanded version).  It doesn't have a glyph, but if you double click it should be inserted. (Sometimes you may need to drag and drop to add.)

Note that you may have to go to the gear wheel at top left and select Customize to add the Unicode category. The Unicode category is under Code Tables.

[image]

Comment: Ahh okay perfect. I did not know about the expanded viewer. Thanks. I should add though that I had to go up to the settings gear -> customize List... -> Code Tables -> tick Unicode for the unicode tab to appear.

Comment: @J.Rehbein good point, I will add it to answer.

Answer (score 9):

If you like to use the terminal, you can do this:

```
printf "\x0c" | pbcopy
```

This pipes a single formfeed character to the `pbcopy`, which stores it in the system clipboard.  You may then paste it into whatever app you need.

Comment: ❤️ this answer :)