# Is there a way to type a character from its ASCII value on a Mac keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

On a Windows PC you may enter an ASCII value from its value typing ALT+ASCII VALUE using the numeric keypad.
For instance:

```
{ = ALT+123
} = ALT+125
` = ALT+96
```

How do you achieve this using a Mac keyboard?
Similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339738/how-do-you-type-a-character-with-its-ascii-code), however there is no specific reply to a generic keyboard usage.....

Use case scenario, a user could be using an editor for coding through a keyboard which is missing some characters, and is often required to enter/type missing keyboard characters....

Comment: Yeah, but it seems to be a bit convoluted, I hoped that there could be an easier way to achieve this. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Can you explain your use case a little more? You're definitely talking about ASCII characters, rather than Unicode?  MacOS does have a Unicode Hex Input mode.

Comment: Unicode Hex Input is basically the same as ALT+ASCII, with access to more characters. What exactly do you mean with "a bit convoluted"?

Comment: Use case scenario, one could be using an editor for coding through a keyboard which is missing some characters, and is often required to enter/type missing keyboard characters....